# gsub to remove escape string

Tags: r, string

```
> pname <- "Ratchanon \"TK\" Chantananuwat (Am)"
> gsub(\"TK\", "", pname)
Error: unexpected string constant in "gsub(\"TK\", ""
```

It is possible to remove the `\"TK\"` in this persons name?

Comment: Use double backslashes + special character, for special characters.

Comment: I am familiar with double backslash for special characters, but am still struggling. With the quotes and the backslash, it is a tough combo of characters to remove

Comment: You need an opening quote to indicate to the R parser you are starting a string, then, an escaped quote to indicating you want to match a quote in `pname` , then TK, then another escaped quote. Finally close with a quote to announce to the R parser your string is complete. `gsub("\"TK\"", "", pname)`

Comment: ahh makes sense. The \ even though it appears in the string is not actually a part of the string that needs to be replaced... we effectively only need to worry about removing the "TK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`:

```r
gsub('\\"TK\\"', "", pname)

#> [1] "Ratchanon  Chantananuwat (Am)"
```

---

Another possible solution, based on `stringr::str_replace`:

```r
library(stringr)

str_remove(pname, '\\"TK\\"')

#> [1] "Ratchanon  Chantananuwat (Am)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you do it in the following manner. First remove the special chars you have in your string. Then apply gsub() to get rid of the letter/word you may like.

```
pname <- "Ratchanon \"TK\" Chantananuwat (Am)"
library(stringr)
pname <- str_replace_all(pname, "[[:punct:]]", "") # removes all the special chars
gsub("TK", "", pname)
```

Hope this might help you!